# crypto-js library generates this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lib')

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

please see these functions and the corresponding codepen:

https://codepen.io/ngodeinweb/pen/QWWevjR

```
function encrypt(){
  var inputan = document.getElementById('inputan').value;
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(inputan, "Ngodeinweb");
  document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = encrypted;
}

function decrypte(){
  var inputan2 = document.getElementById('inputan2').value;
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(inputan2, "Ngodeinweb");
  document.getElementById('app2').innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

The code there works, but when seeing the browser developer console, this error have occured when the page was loaded:

[image]

How can this be solved?

Thanks